# probability of aces being in the same half

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have a deck of 52 cards which is separated in two halves.
I have to calculate the probability that 2 aces are in the first half and 2 in the second and also the probability that in one of the halves there are no aces.

What I've got so far:

I know all the different ways separate the deck in two halves are $C^{52}_{26}$. Now if we fix those 4 aces, we are left with 22 other cards to be partitioned out of 48 - $C^{48}_{22}$. Assuming what I've got so far is correct I'm left with calculating the ways 4 aces can go in the 2 halves so that there are 2 in the first, and 2 in the second.

Comment: Have you heard about hypergeometric probability?

Comment: @Arthur, yes! It does look like hypergeometric now that you say it. It's still that this problem is in the section before distributions, so there should be a naive approach too. I'll try to solve it with hypergeometric distribution too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are $\binom{52}{26}$ ways to select half the cards in the deck.  We want the probability that half the deck contains exactly two aces.  If it does, then we must select two of the four aces and $24$ of the remaining $48$ cards in the deck.  Hence, the desired probability is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{4}{2}\dbinom{48}{24}}{\dbinom{52}{26}}$$
A similar approach can be used to determine the probability that no aces are in half the deck.